# How to access a struct slice element key directly in a template file

Tags: templates, go

I am loading some template files and attempting to compile them with some structs I've defined.

The following example is working. I'd like to know if there is a better way of formatting my **templateFile** to directly access **config.Servers[1].Ip1** without needing two sets of **{{}}**

templateFile:
    {{$a := index .Servers 1 }}{{$a.Ip1}} some extra text

learn.go:

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "os"
)

type Server struct {
    Ip1 string
    Ip2 string
}

type Configuration struct {
    Servers []Server
}

func main() {
    someServers := []Server{
        {
            Ip1: "1.1.1.1",
            Ip2: "2.2.2.2",
        },
        {
            Ip1: "3.3.3.3",
            Ip2: "4.4.4.4",
        },
    }
    config := Configuration{
        Servers: someServers,
    }

    tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("./templateFile")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this:
https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/

You have to use {{}} in your HTML template, if you wish to access any Struct variable.

Comment: Sorry maybe it wasn't clear. I understand I need to have {{}} in my template. I'm wondering if I can avoid having two sets of them. Can I do this without assigning to a variable $a?

Comment: You can use () inside the {{}} like this: {{ (index .Servers 1).lp1 }}

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thanks mgagnon!